# How to colour tables in R - Conditional Fomatting

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I want to assign colors to tables in R.

[image]

Is it possible to create a table like this in R - where the predicted class is colored green when it is green and red when it is red.

The above table displayed is done in excel.

Comment: You can do program this yourself using some html and the [DT library](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/)

Comment: This question is extremely vague and does not show any research effort. Please read these tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For example, you do not even  mention your desired output format.

Comment: The `XLConnect` package can change formatting in .xls or .xlsx files. Besides, google something like "R color xls cells"

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP wants to color excel cells.... they specifically said a table in R, although it's a bit unclear. If its an excel table that should be colored go with @akraf 's suggestoin if not, check my post below

Comment: It is not to do in excel files. I want to view a data frame in R which will generate this formatting. Coloring in excel is easy and excel has the feature of conditional formatting. @shayaa the link is for html pages and I want to do this in R data frames. Though thanks for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(formattable)
df <- data.frame(
  Machine=c("1","2","3","4","5","6"),
  Predicted_Class=c("green","red","red","green","green","green")
)

formattable(df, 
            list(area(4:6,2) ~ color_tile("green", "green"), 
                 area(1,2) ~ color_tile("green", "green"), 
                 area(2:3,2) ~ color_tile("red", "red")))
```

[image]